# Android SDK. call onDestroy() directly in scripting

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-maps

I have an android app, ATV Trail Locator (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wmk3cA2i2vI), that uses google maps.

Because my server is used for web serving and the Android app, I want to be able to kill the app in case it takes up too many server resources by setting a variable in my mysql database.

Because the application communicates with The server every second, it can get this variable and then shutdown the program if it is equal to 0.

I tried to call onDestroy() directly, but my program crashed. Do I need to use super.onDestroy()  in order to kill the program without requiring back button push?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling `finish()` instead?

If this doesn't work, please post a code sample and your logcat errors so we can see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Call finish() whenever you want to kill the current activity you're on.  It'll call onDestroy() along with all the other required Activity lifecycle methods that need to be called.